# AspectJ Compile time weaving fails for streams

Tags: java, generics, java-stream, aspectj

I am getting below error when aspectj compiler runs.

```
[ERROR] Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Object> to List<Tag>
```

My code is,

```
        final List<Tag> customTags = 
             pathVariables.entrySet().stream().filter(entry -> {
                return tagList.contains(entry.getKey());
            }).map(tag -> {
                return new Tag() {

                    @Override
                    public String getValue() {
                        logger.info("Key for the attached tag is: {}", 
                        tag.getKey());
                        return tag.getKey();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public String getKey() {
                        logger.info("Value for the attached tag is: {}", (String)tag.getValue());
                        return (String) tag.getValue();
                    }
                };
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.7</version>
    </dependency>
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>       <!-- use this goal to weave all your main classes -->
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>  <!-- use this goal to weave all your test classes -->
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
</plugin>
```

Things that I have tried,
1. Adding properties so as to tell maven compiler plugin to comply with java 8

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
</properties>
```

2. Changing AspectJ version to 1.8.13

In both of the cases I got same error. If I use,

```
final List customTags = ...
```

with the same code I do not get this error. Am I missing anything?

3. Tried running dummy code of similar structure,

   ```
   Map<String, Object> HOSTING1 = new HashMap<>();
   HOSTING1.put("1", "linode.com");
   HOSTING1.put("2", "heroku.com");
   HOSTING1.put("3", "digitalocean.com");
   HOSTING1.put("4", "aws.amazon.com");

   List<String> tagList = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");

   final List<Tag> customTags = HOSTING1.entrySet().stream().filter(entry - 
   > {
       return tagList.contains(entry.getKey());
   }).map(tag -> {
       return new Tag() {

           @Override
           public String getValue() {

               System.out.println("Value for the attached tag is: {}" + tag.getValue());
               return (String) tag.getValue();
           }

           @Override
           public String getKey() {
               System.out.println("Key for the attached tag is: {}" + tag.getKey());
               return (String) tag.getKey();
           }
       };
   }).collect(Collectors.toList());
   ```

Comment: It seems there is nothing to do with *AspectJ*, it's your code. Would you please test it with a smaller demo and post the error then?

Comment: I already tested it with dummy code runs fine. Error is thrown while running ApectJ compiler through maven.

Comment: You might try explicitly specifying the generic type on the `map` call i.e. `.<Tag>map(` ...

Comment: Sorry, I **cannot** reproduce your problem...any way to re-produce it?

Comment: Yes explicitly specifying <Tag>.map(tag -> {... helped! Without that AspectJ compiler was causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly specifying .map(tag -> {... helped! Without that AspectJ compiler was causing the issue. Code is,

```
final List<Tag> customTags = 
         pathVariables.entrySet().stream().filter(entry -> {
            return tagList.contains(entry.getKey());
        }).<Tag>map(tag -> {
            return new Tag() {

                @Override
                public String getValue() {
                    logger.info("Key for the attached tag is: {}", 
                    tag.getKey());
                    return tag.getKey();
                }

                @Override
                public String getKey() {
                    logger.info("Value for the attached tag is: {}", (String)tag.getValue());
                    return (String) tag.getValue();
                }
            };
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I had exactly the same issue recently, I highly suspect a bug somewhere between Java and aspectJ libs. Hopefully, you saved my day :)